# Validate the date in JS?

Tags: javascript

Trying to do this date validation and this is the code I came up with. It doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function isValidDate(dateStr) {
    // Checks for the following valid date formats:
    // MM/DD/YY   MM/DD/YYYY   MM-DD-YY   MM-DD-YYYY

    var dateStr = document.getElementById("dob").value;

    var datePat = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})\2(\d{2}|\d{4})$/;

    var matchArray = dateStr.match(datePat);   

    if (matchArray == null){
        errMsg = errMsg + "Date is not in a valid format.";
        result = false;
    }

    var month = matchArray[1];

    var day = matchArray[3];

    var year = matchArray[4];

    if (month < 1 || month > 12){ 
        errMsg = errMsg + "Month must be between 1 and 12.";
        result = false;
    }

    if (day < 1 || day > 31){
        errMsg = errMsg + "Day must be between 1 and 31.";
        result = false;
    }

    if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) && day==31){
        errMsg = errMsg + "Month "+month+" doesn't have 31 days!";
        result = false;
    }

    if (month == 2){ // check for leap year

        var isleap = (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));

        if (day>29 || (day==29 && !isleap)){
        errMsg = errMsg + "February " + year + " doesn't have " + day + " days!";
        result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;      // date is valid
}
```

Comment: format your code to make it readable

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it doesn't work". Do you get any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Blazemonger No. There are no errors displayed. Nothing happens at all.

Comment: How did you test this? Add that part of code as well, like `isValidDate("29-02-1988")`

Comment: @sabithpocker I test it in the HTML DOB field. I call the function isValidDate(dateStr); outside. When i submit the form it doesnt show any errors at all.

Comment: could you show us how you are calling the function in jsfiddle? Because I spotted that you forgot to declare `result ` and `errMsg ` variables.

Answer (score 0):

why are you adding datestr as parameter when you are accessing it through

```
var dateStr = document.getElementById("dob").value;
```

secondly i put some console and try to run this function and find out you are getting month as date and date as month. Just put console.log and check it . rest you need to declare variable before using it none of the variables are initialized it do it and all will work fine. here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function isValidDate(dateStr) {
// Checks for the following valid date formats:
// MM/DD/YY   MM/DD/YYYY   MM-DD-YY   MM-DD-YYYY

var datePat = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})\2(\d{2}|\d{4})$/;

var matchArray = dateStr.match(datePat); 

var errMsg;

var result = true;

if (matchArray == null){
    errMsg = errMsg + "Date is not in a valid format.";
    result = false;
}

var day= matchArray[1];

var month= matchArray[3];

var year = matchArray[4];


if (month < 1 || month > 12){ 
    errMsg = errMsg + "Month must be between 1 and 12.";
    result = false;
}

if (day < 1 || day > 31){
    errMsg = errMsg + "Day must be between 1 and 31.";
    result = false;
}

if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) && day==31){
    errMsg = errMsg + "Month "+month+" doesn't have 31 days!";
    result = false;
}

if (month == 2){ // check for leap year

    var isleap = (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));

    if (day>29 || (day==29 && !isleap)){
    errMsg = errMsg + "February " + year + " doesn't have " + day + " days!";
    result = false;
    }
}

console.log(result);      // date is valid
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First error: don't redefine `dateStr` at the top of your function if you're passing it in as an argument — or else don't pass it in as an argument.

Second and third error: initialize `errMsg = '';` and `result = true;` at the start of your function.

```
function isValidDate(dateStr) {
    // Checks for the following valid date formats:
    // MM/DD/YY   MM/DD/YYYY   MM-DD-YY   MM-DD-YYYY

//    var dateStr = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    var errMsg = '';
    var result = true;
```

or:

```
function isValidDate() {
    // Checks for the following valid date formats:
    // MM/DD/YY   MM/DD/YYYY   MM-DD-YY   MM-DD-YYYY

    var dateStr = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    var errMsg = '';
    var result = true;
```